# Duplicate the camera streaming with FFMPEG and Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, streaming

Python: 3.6, Ubuntu 18.04, OpenCV 4.1.0

I have an IP camera that streams video data in H.264/H.265 encoding. I would like to take this video stream and duplicate this stream into multiple streams by using Python without any encoding or decoding. I am supposing that the camera stream is `rtsp` protocol. The output of multiple streams can be any types as long as the system can the get the real time processing.

Comment: The architecture of system would be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiYXf.png

Comment: better put image in question, not in comment - more people will see it.

Comment: what did you try? What did you find in Google ? Where is your code? Where is your FULL error message?

Comment: I've tried FFMPEG-Python library https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python to solve this problem. The main program will capture the raw frames and convert them into bytes,  the ffmpeg will create a RTMP (Real Time Message Protocol) from these frames. Currently, I only create 1 video streaming, I want to create multple video streaming at the same resolution as source.

Comment: it may need to run `ffmpeg` in many threads to get many streams. Similar way works WWW servers. When new client connect to server then server create new thread to work with this client.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The simplest approach could be creating many threads to get a number of streams as we want. However, it can affect seriously to the CPU usage because of my limited resource.

Comment: using Google I found in ffmpeg documentation [Creating Multiple Outputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs). But more intersting was link to [tee](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) which has `"The tee muxer can be used to write the same data to several outputs, such as files or streams"`  and `"With the tee muxer, the audio and video data will be encoded only once."`

Comment: I wondering if wouldn't be better to send stream to some C/C++ program which will send it to clients - ie. web server `nginx`. This post describe how to use [nginx to broadcast stream video](https://opensource.com/article/19/1/basic-live-video-streaming-server) but it doesn't show how to use it with python script. But maybe it is some good direction.